# File_get_contents to Curl

Tags: php, curl

I would like to know what's the easiest to way to transform my code below to use cURL.

I'm asking this because I have performed every test in localhost and it was working fine until I pushed it to my server and I have read that I should use cURL but it looks so complicated for what I need to do.

```
$userid = file_get_contents("http://www.someexample.com/api/findusers/".$names."?key=".$key, NULL, NULL, 8);
```

Comment: If you just need to get the contents of the URL, `file_get_contents()` is fine, you don't need to use `cURL`.

Comment: Does your server have `allow_url_fopen` disabled?

Comment: now it does, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the simplest way to perform a get request:

```
<?php 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.someexample.com/api/findusers/".$names."?key=".$key); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        $userID = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```